# Apache Solr:"undefined field publish_date"

Tags: solr

I have added a new field in my `schema.xml` file like below.
 and restarted the solr.
I am getting below error message When I am executing the below query in solr admin

### My Query

```
cat: content AND (name: content* OR genre: content*) AND sku:54 AND  NOT publish_date:*
```

### Error Message

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 2,
    "params": {
      "debugQuery": "true",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "cat: content AND (name: content* OR genre: content*) AND sku:54 AND  NOT publish_date:*",
      "_": "1501837724963",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "undefined field publish_date",
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

Anyone Please Help me, if I missed anything or if I did any mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, do you have a field named `publish_date`? What is its definition? Does it show up under "Analysis" under Solr admin or under the schema explorer?

Comment: yes I have a filed added in schema.xml like below.

<field name="publish_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />

but its not listed under the field name dropdown under analysis

Comment: I got the Issue resolved.I just used the command 'sudo service solr restart ' to restart the solr service again and thats it I got the result.

Thank you MatsLindh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've made changes to your schema (in non-cloud mode), you'll have to either restart Solr or reload the core. The latter is preferred, as that allows queries to be served while the schema is being reloaded. You can perform a reload in the admin interface under "Core Admin", or through the API by making a request to:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=corename
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I also needed to add the new field in Solr's schema.xml file. I my case I added this line in it:
`<field name="publish_date" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />`